# Python script is running in the IDE, but not in the terminal (Kafka)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

This may or may not be Kafka related, but I encountered this while learning Kafka. I've got a python producer script that looks like this:

```py
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from json import dumps


class Producer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
            value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8')
        )

    def push_client(self, data):
        self.connection.send('client-pusher', value=data)


data = {
    "first_name": "Davey",
    "email": "davey@dave.com",
    "group_id": 3,
    "date": "2021-12-12"
}

producer = Producer()
producer.push_client(data)
```

I'm running the Kafka Broker in Docker, and the messages get consumed on the other end by this script:

```py
import json
from datetime import date
from typing import Optional

from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Client(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    email: str
    group_id: Optional[int] = None
    date: date


consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'client-pusher',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my-group-id',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
)

while True:
    msg_pack = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=500)

    for tp, messages in msg_pack.items():
        for message in messages:
            client = Client(**message.value)
            print(client)
```

The consumer script listens for new messages on an infinite loop. I can run the consumer in terminal or in vscode and it will always print out the data dict from the producer, but ONLY if I run the producer script in Visual Studio code.

If I run the producer script in the terminal  with

```
python producer.py
```

the messages don't come through to the consumer. There are no runtime errors (print statements in the producer come through fine). I cannot for the life of me see what's different about the environment in my IDE.

I have different virtual environments governing both scripts. I've tried running the producer with the full path to the venv, copied straight from vscode's terminal, for example

```
/home/me/whatever/dummy-producer/.venv/bin/python producer.py
```

I've also printed out everything in `sys.path` – they're identical between the IDE and the terminal.

What else might I try to find the difference between vscode's execution and the terminal's? I'm using `zsh`, if that matters.

Comment: You're not waiting for the producer to finish. Call `self.connection.flush()` after the send

Comment: Nice, that was it! Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka clients don't immediately send the messages; if you have less than the default batch size and the app exits, you're effectively dropping events.

If you want to send immediately, you need one more method in the producer

```
def push_client(self, data):
    self.connection.send('client-pusher', value=data)
    self.connection.flush()
```